# Serilog creates a new file after 2 KB

Tags: c#, serilog, rollingfilesink

I am using rolling file sink.

Following is my code of initialization:

```
Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"L:\logs\Api-{Date}.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: null)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Here is the line to log:

```
Log.Information(message);
```

But after 2 KB, it creates a new file.

I don't know what's going wrong.

**Update**

This is my logger class:

```
public class Logger
{
    public Logger()
    {
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"L:\logs\Api-{Date}.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: null)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public void Log(LogRequestParameters logRequestParameters, LoggingLevels loggingLevel)
    {
        var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logRequestParameters);

        switch (loggingLevel)
        {
            case LoggingLevels.Verbose:
                Serilog.Log.Verbose(message);
                break;

            case LoggingLevels.Debug:
                Serilog.Log.Debug(message);
                break;

            case LoggingLevels.Information:
                Serilog.Log.Information(message);
                break;

            case LoggingLevels.Warning:
                Serilog.Log.Warning(message);
                break;

            case LoggingLevels.Error:
                Serilog.Log.Warning(message);
                break;

            case LoggingLevels.Fatal:
                Serilog.Log.Fatal(message);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my caller class:

```
public class Caller
{   
    logRequestParameters.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    logRequestParameters.Level = "Debug";
    logRequestParameters.MachineName = Environment.MachineName;
    logRequestParameters.Type = "Request";
    logRequestParameters.Request = request;

    Logger logger = new Logger();

    logger.Log(logRequestParameters, LoggingLevels.Information);
}
```

Comment: I took your code above and called `Log.Information(new String('x', 1024))` 5 times and it created a single 5K file.  Can you provide more details of your application and how you're logging?  The code you showed does not split the file after 2k (using Serilog 2.2.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is creating a new logger instance for each event. You need to create a *single* logger and use it for each logging call.

There is some further information on the lifecycle of Serilog loggers [in the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers).

Comment: Thanks! But how can I create a single logger and use it throughout the application.
In my current application, I created a logger class. I want to use this on different location. Moreover, I want to create one constructor which will take File Path and Minimum Level as input. So that for different purpose, I can log in different files.

Comment: Thanks, this reply made me find an accidental extra IoC registration for a class